# OnScroll Event is not working - Angular Dart

Tags: angular, scroll, dart, angular-dart, onscroll

I have an issue with the `window.onScroll` event. The event was never triggered.

That's my first try:

```
  @override
  void ngOnInit() {

    window.onScroll.listen((Event event) => print("it works.."));
  }
```

But it's not working.

I basiclly need the onScroll event. Not more. So i tried the "old school" way in Html

My second try:

```
    <div (scroll)="onScroll()">

       <!--Some content-->

    </div>
```

But it's also not working.

What is the best solution to get the scroll event in AngularDart?

By the way, i use AngularDart 5.

Comment: The JS way with `(scroll)="onScroll()"` is not expected to work. The first one looks better - you'll need to be sure that the `ngOnInit` is being executed. Note that if you're changing some binding in response to the scroll event angular won't pick it up unless you also tell angular to detect changes again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple solutions to this problem.

The first thing that you need to do is get a reference to the HTML element that you want to get scroll events from. I pretend that this element looks like the following (in your components `.html` file):

`<div>Some scrollable content</div>`

As far as I know, there are two ways of getting a reference to an HTML element in AngularDart.

**First solution:**

Use the [`@ViewChild`](https://webdev.dartlang.org/api/angular/angular/ViewChild-class) annotation. For this to work, you need to add a [template reference variable](https://webdev.dartlang.org/angular/guide/template-syntax#template-reference-variables--var-) to the `div`. I call it "scrollable", however it is up to you how you will call it.

`<div #scrollable>Some scrollable content</div>`

Then add the following property to your component class:

```
@ViewChild("scrollable")
  Element scrollable;
```

**Second (but not recommended) solution:**

Add an id to the `div` (the name of the id does not matter): 
Get the reference to the `div` by using [`document.getElementById()`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.0.0/dart-html/Document/getElementById.html) provided by [`dart:html`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.0.0/dart-html/dart-html-library.html):

```
Element scrollable = document.getElementById('scrollable')
```

The problem with this solution is, that `document` is not available in any of the AngularDart life cycle hooks as far as i know.

**Finally**, to listen to the `onScroll` stream of the `scrollable` element just do the following somewhere in your component class:

```
something.onScroll.listen((Event event) => print("Hurray, it works :)"))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
div.onScroll.listen((ev) {
});
```

this pretty much works on my tests.
Are you sure that the place you are adding the listener is the one that is in fact scrolling?

Comment: What is `div` in this case?